# Get string from 'To' action in wso2

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I created an api in wso2ei like this :

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test" context="/Test" version="/" version-type="context">
 <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/CheckTest" inSequence="TestSequence">
  <outSequence>
    <send/>
  </outSequence>
 </resource>
 <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/TransferTest" inSequence="TestSequence">
  <outSequence>
    <send/>
  </outSequence>
 </resource>
</api>
```

After sending message to sequence i want to get url-mapping value as property. 'To' Action is /Test/CheckTest for CheckTest and /Test/TransferTest for TransferTest. i want to get url-mapping value or resource selected dynamically. how can i do this?

```
<property name="urlMappingValue" expression=?/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use resource with uri-template , and then access uri part in property through uri.var.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test" context="/Test">
   <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/{method}">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="method" expression="get-property('uri.var.method')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <switch source="get-property('uri.var.method')">
            <case regex="CheckTest">
                 ... Your logic for Check Test...
            </case>
            <case regex="TransferTest">
                 ... Your logic for Transfer Test...
            </case>           
         </switch>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```